# QMake: Get full path of output executable

Tags: qt, qmake

In my .pro file for QMake I would like to run install_name_tool to replace some library paths. For this I need to determine path to my output executable. Particularly on macx the path to executable looks like this

```
<build_directory>/<configuration_name>/<target_name>.app/Contents/MacOS/<target_name>
```

I figured out that

```
message("build_directory=$${OUT_PWD}")
message("target_name=$${TARGET}")
```

Is there a QMake variable to populate configuration_name?

By default it is supposed to return "release" for release configurations and "debug" for debug configurations. From what I saw online people just explicitly define $${DESTDIR}

```
debug { DESTDIR = debug }
release { DESTDIR = release }
debug_and_release { DESTDIR = bin }
```

if not defined message("DESTDIR=$$DESTDIR") returns empty value for DESTDIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DEBUG_OR_RELEASE = debug
}  else {
    DEBUG_OR_RELEASE = release
}
```

So then the full output path is:

```
$${OUT_PWD}/$${DEBUG_OR_RELEASE}
```